# Can't select VS2017 in build definition

Tags: visual-studio-2017, build-server, build-definition

I have installed a build agent on my build server (WS2016)
I have installed Visual Studion 2017 Professional to my build server
Why can't I select Visual Studio 2017 in my build definition?

I have selected "Latest" now, but the build fails due to

"my file".cs (240, 65)
"my file".cs(240,65): Error CS1525: Invalid Expressiong '.'.
The Code in this Line:

```
private void OnOutput(EbcMessage message) { this.Output?.Invoke(message);}
```

I also get the warning "Visual Studio not found. Try installing a supported version of Visual Studio. See the task definition for a list of supported versions."
On My Workstation the Code builds fine.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you by any chance figure this out? Things were working fine for me until I ran an update for VS 2017 on the build server.

Comment: Yes, I had to update my tfs to current version.

Answer (score 0):

After I updated my TFS to current version, things worked fine.

Comment: Would you mind telling me what TFS version you are running now where things work fine? I'm running TFS 15.112.26307.0 and it did not work with VS 15.3.3. I rolled back to VS 15.2 and got things working; but I'd like to be current on my versions again.

Comment: I am currently using TFS 2017 (15.112.26307.0)

Comment: Interesting, we're both using the same TFS version. I'm pretty sure VS 15.3.3 broke this for me. I'll just wait until 15.3.5 to be safe and attempt to upgrade; I know 14.3.4. is already out but I'll play it safe. Thanks for sharing!